# How to download 32 bit ubuntu on a 64 bit machine?

Tags: system-installation

My laptop is a 64 bit machine, but I need to download a 32 bit version of the Ubuntu OS because my school has said that a particular program I need 'was made with the intention that the user will not be running it on a 64 bit version of the Ubuntu OS'. That is pretty much true because I have tried many ways to run it, and all my attempts have failed.

The problem is that after I have downloaded the client for the 32 bit version of Ubuntu (I'm sure it's the client for 32 bit because I have even redownloaded it) and installed it into my computer, the system settings in Ubuntu will say that I have the 64 bit of the OS installed. I check this by going to system settings > Details > OS type. My question is... how do I install a 32 bit version of the Ubuntu OS on a 64 bit window 7 machine?

Comment: Which file did you download, and how are you installing?

Comment: Im pretty sure you have downloaded a 64bit Ubuntu. Please doublecheck what did you downloaded. 32 bit distro has i386 in the iso filename. 64bit distro used to have amd64 in the iso filename.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your situation correctly you already have Windows 7 64-bit installed on your laptop.  If you want to keep Windows installed but also use Ubuntu, there are a few options I can think of:

- Use a [live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)
- Use [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)
- Use VirtualBox
- Use a dual boot

The VirtualBox option will definitely allow you to use the 32-bit version of Ubuntu but the others should as well (someone can correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Good info, but a live cd is not really practical for this situation. You might mention VMWare Player, which is free like VirtualBox. You could greatly improve the answer by providing some info on setting up a virtual guest and dual booting, or linking to previous answers that do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **direct link** to download the official and extended support version of ubuntu (12.04):

## 32bit:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/questions?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts

Just select your amount of donation, you can also set all to zero and hit the download button.

Make sure the ***name of the file*** is: `ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386.iso`

**I just checked the link, it should work.**

Now, instructions on how preparing method of installation depending on operating system and media available:

### Windows

- [How to burn a DVD on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)
- [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
- [Installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with the Windows installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows)

### OS X

- [How to burn a DVD on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx)
- [How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)

### Ubuntu

- [How to burn a DVD on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu)
- [How to create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

### And finally.

[Installation instructions.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support)

I hope this was helpful

### :-)